# Resetting the values that do not meet the specified condition

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say, I have a numpy array `x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and two variables, i.e `min = 3` and `max = 7`. What would be the most efficient way to set `x` values to `0` when they go beyond the range specified by `min` and `max` variables, i.e `>3 && <7`, so the final result would be `x_after = [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this:

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.where(np.logical_or(x<3, x>7), 0, x)
array([0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0])
#or without `np.logical_or` call.
>>> np.where((x < 3) | (x > 7), 0, x)
array([0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged the question with `numpy`, here is a NumPy solution:

```
In [19]: x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [20]: min_val, max_val = 3, 7

In [21]: x[(x < min_val) | (x > max_val)] = 0

In [22]: x
Out[22]: array([0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0])
```

This modifies the array in-place; it's easy to make a copy if you need to.

Comment: My choice is this over @Ashwini 's, because it is both more concise and easier to read.